# JQuery UI Sortable Elements and Input Fields not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

Updating because I found the solution to this which I posted as an answer to my own question: The disableSelection() method needs to be removed.  Original post here for reference in case anyone encounters this same issue:

:::::::::::::::::::

I am using the **JQuery UI Sortable** method and I found a strange bug with **Firefox** and **input fields**.  For some reason, input fields that are added to the sortable elements are not clickable in Firefox.  You cannot focus on them unless you right-click them.  This issue is not present in Chrome.

See JS Fiddle here and note this is only an issue if you view it in Firefox.  For the record I am on Firefox 33 and I have also reproduced this on Firefox 32:

http://jsfiddle.net/t1795601/

Here is the code from the fiddle.  It almost exactly matches what JQuery UI uses for their demo with the exception of an added input field to demonstrate the issue:

Libraries:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

My HTML:

```
<h4>An input outside of the sortable boxes works:</h4>
<input type="text" placeholder="this input works"/>
<br/>

<h4>But if you try to add an input field inside one of the sortable boxes, you cannot click it in Firefox.</h4>
<h6>Note that the markup for the sortable boxes is copied directly from jquery.com as is the corresponding CSS and JS</h6>
   <div class="sortable-lists">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight"><input type="text" placeholder="this input does not"/></li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
 #sortable1, #sortable2 {
border: 1px solid #eee;
width: 40%;
min-height: 20px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 1.2em;
width: 90%;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

My JS:

```
 $(function() {
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Posting an answer to my own question as I figured out the issue.  It's the .disableSelection() method.  Once that is removed, the input boxes work in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Remove .disableSelection(); from you JS, it will make input work in Firefox.
Had exactly same issue.

Your updated JS should look like:
    $(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({connectWith: ".connectedSortable"});
    });